# Not getting the proper response from retrofit api call

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit API to get data, and for that, I've created the POJO classes as required.

Here are my POJO classes, 1. Report

```
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

2. Datum

   ```
    @SerializedName("_id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("seq")
    @Expose
    private Integer seq;
    @SerializedName("imei")
    @Expose
    private String imei;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private String lon;
    @SerializedName("etype")
    @Expose
    private String etype;
    @SerializedName("nos")
    @Expose
    private String nos;
    @SerializedName("rssi")
    @Expose
    private String rssi;
    @SerializedName("hac")
    @Expose
    private String hac;
    @SerializedName("spd")
    @Expose
    private String spd;
    @SerializedName("btv")
    @Expose
    private String btv;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private String dt;
    @SerializedName("erpm")
    @Expose
    private String erpm;
    @SerializedName("thpos")
    @Expose
    private String thpos;
    @SerializedName("erntm")
    @Expose
    private String erntm;
    @SerializedName("fgrl")
    @Expose
    private String fgrl;
    @SerializedName("dtml")
    @Expose
    private String dtml;
    @SerializedName("flvl")
    @Expose
    private String flvl;
    @SerializedName("ftype")
    @Expose
    private String ftype;
    @SerializedName("eot")
    @Expose
    private String eot;
    @SerializedName("ect")
    @Expose
    private String ect;
    @SerializedName("odm")
    @Expose
    private String odm;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("__v")
    @Expose
    private Integer v;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getSeq() {
        return seq;
    }

    public void setSeq(Integer seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
    }

    public String getImei() {
        return imei;
    }

    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getEtype() {
        return etype;
    }

    public void setEtype(String etype) {
        this.etype = etype;
    }

    public String getNos() {
        return nos;
    }

    public void setNos(String nos) {
        this.nos = nos;
    }

    public String getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }

    public void setRssi(String rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    public String getHac() {
        return hac;
    }

    public void setHac(String hac) {
        this.hac = hac;
    }

    public String getSpd() {
        return spd;
    }

    public void setSpd(String spd) {
        this.spd = spd;
    }

    public String getBtv() {
        return btv;
    }

    public void setBtv(String btv) {
        this.btv = btv;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(String dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public String getErpm() {
        return erpm;
    }

    public void setErpm(String erpm) {
        this.erpm = erpm;
    }

    public String getThpos() {
        return thpos;
    }

    public void setThpos(String thpos) {
        this.thpos = thpos;
    }

    public String getErntm() {
        return erntm;
    }

    public void setErntm(String erntm) {
        this.erntm = erntm;
    }

    public String getFgrl() {
        return fgrl;
    }

    public void setFgrl(String fgrl) {
        this.fgrl = fgrl;
    }

    public String getDtml() {
        return dtml;
    }

    public void setDtml(String dtml) {
        this.dtml = dtml;
    }

    public String getFlvl() {
        return flvl;
    }

    public void setFlvl(String flvl) {
        this.flvl = flvl;
    }

    public String getFtype() {
        return ftype;
    }

    public void setFtype(String ftype) {
        this.ftype = ftype;
    }

    public String getEot() {
        return eot;
    }

    public void setEot(String eot) {
        this.eot = eot;
    }

    public String getEct() {
        return ect;
    }

    public void setEct(String ect) {
        this.ect = ect;
    }

    public String getOdm() {
        return odm;
    }

    public void setOdm(String odm) {
        this.odm = odm;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(Integer v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
   ```

Here is how I tried to fetch the data in form of a `Datum list` using the `Report` class.

Here is the activity code...

```
Call<Report> call = RetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getApi()
                    .getAlltheReports(reportModel);


            call.enqueue(new Callback<Report>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Report> call, Response<Report> response) {

                    Log.d("responseBodyyyyyyyyy", String.valueOf(response.body()));

                    Report example = response.body();

                    if (example != null) {
                        Log.d("gettingNull", "DATA");

                        List<Datum> data = response.body().getData();
                        Log.d("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", String.valueOf(data));


                    } else {
                        Log.d("gettingNull", "Null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Report> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("error", String.valueOf(t));
                }
            });
```

In, the retrofit call `reportModel` is nothing but JSON data.

For reference,

```
ReportModel:

ReportModelJson reportModel = new ReportModelJson("353081090133664", "Asia/Kolkata", "02-06-2022", "02-10-2022");
```

And I'm posting the API call like this:-

```
@POST("getonlyselect")
Call<Report> getAlltheReports(
        @Body ReportModelJson ReportModelJson
);
```

This is I tried to fetch the data, but instead of getting the proper response, I'm getting the `packagename@xxxx`.

For reference:

```
com.example.abcd.Screens.Models.Datum@42df5e8
```

The response that I'm getting is like this:-

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "61fed1d527824e063e318124",
        "seq": 21,
        "imei": "353081090133664",
        "lat": "22.472927",
        "lon": "70.080795",
        "etype": "stop",
        "nos": "5",
        "rssi": "-51",
        "hac": "1.5",
        "spd": "2",
        "btv": "12.34",
        "address": "abcd",
        "dt": "1644089809000",
        "erpm": "N",
        "thpos": "N",
        "erntm": "N",
        "fgrl": "N",
        "dtml": "N",
        "flvl": "N",
        "ftype": "N",
        "eot": "N",
        "ect": "N",
        "odm": "N",
        "date": "2022-02-05T19:36:53.087Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

}

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: It looks like ```Log``` method prints the object reference instead of values inside. Try ```Log.d("Data", data.get(0).id)```. This will print id of first data object. If data is empty you might get an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your code, there is not any error in the retrofit API call, There is an error in the printing value that you got from API.

As I can see in your code you have used the below code to print data that you got from API.

```
List<Datum> data = response.body().getData();
 Log.d("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", String.valueOf(data));
```

Also, `Data` is an array that you are trying to print using `Log.d`. So if you want to print your data so you can set for loop to print every object data like below.

```
List<Datum> data = response.body().getData();
for(int l=0; l<data.size(); l++)
{
  Log.d("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", data.get(l)._id())
 }
```

I hope, this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I got the idea, but when I fire a loop then I get an error saying -> .lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1223, Size: 1223

Comment: I think you have added = like this l<=data.size(). If yes, remove "="